# ConnectionString ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDataSource1"].ToString());


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlDataSource1"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SqlDataSource3;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\SqlDataSource3.mdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Should that work now?

Is at ConnectionStrings["XXX"] has to be placed Name or Initial Catalog of connectionStrings?

Comment: Don't use `.ToString()` on a connection string, you should use `.ConnectionString`.

Comment: Your question should also post the exception/error message that you got. This may help users understand your issue more.

Answer (score 0):

As shown on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), the index value is the name of the connection string.  Therefore your code is correct.

Now wondering why you have posted the question.  Does your code not work?

Comment: Does any other action work (list, read etc)?  Does the database exist?

Comment: So from query i can do anything, but at front page to insert is not possible, i have no error messages!

Comment: But If I look at Dataconnections the Name is set SqlDataSource3 at Identity but shows in the List as SqlDataSource1!!

Comment: What is "Dataconnections" ?  If you can query, then your connection string is correct.  If 'insert is not possible' can you post your insert code?

Comment: Sorry, but it is maybe an Serverside problem, other WebApp is not working even now, did perfect before, reinstalled MS SQL LocalDB to EXPRESS 2017, so it is not an Code Problem!

Comment: Man man man, it was just easy, I had an JavaScript to close Window after inserting the Data, put that away now it works, very fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<add name="SqlDataSource1" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SqlDataSource3;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

and then:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDataSource1"].ConnectionString);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So than I can not work with the Local Datasource(DatabaseFile) anymore!?

Comment: This is missing: AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\SqlDataSource3.mdf

Comment: Even SSPI is not set, by yours! So it is than not an Hosted App?

Comment: You don't need AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\SqlDataSource3.mdf because there is 'Initial Catalog'. It serves as a database name only.